# How to add a localField in a lookup field using $lookup and its pipeline, in MongoDb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, web-applications, social-media

I'm trying to figure out how I can add a **`localField`** in a **`lookup field`** using $lookup and pipeline.

So I have a **`user`** schema that looks like below (there is the **`"added_at"`** field I want to keep in the final result)

```
 User {
   _id: ObjectId("123456789xx")
   first_name: "Sam",
   last_name: "Jones",
   email: "samjones@gmail.com",
   inbox: [
      {
          participant: ObjectId("1XXXXXXXXX"),
          added_at: "12:00:00 09/21/2021"
      },
      {
          participant: ObjectId("2XXXXXXXXX"),
          added_at: "12:00:00 11/21/2022"
      },
   ]
}
```

Now I'm using $lookup to populate the **`participant`** fields

```
{
   from: "Users",
   localField: "inbox.participant",
   foreignField:"_id",
   as: "participants",
   pipeline:[
      { $project: {first_name:1, last_name:1, _id: 1}}
   ]
}
```

Then I get:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("123456789xx")
  first_name: "Sam",
  last_name: "Jones",
  email: "samjones@gmail.com",
  inbox:...,
  participants: [
     { _id: ObjectId("1xxxxx"), first_name: "John", last_name:"Doe"},
     { _id: ObjectId("2xxxxx"), first_name: "Jack", last_name: "Smith"}
  ]
}
```

I want to be able to keep the **`"added_at"`** field in each one of the participants, how can I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm uncertain about your data model.  Is this a `"$lookup"` from `Users` to `Users`?

Comment: Yes, so "participant" is also a user

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add another `$set` step:

```
db.Users.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "Users",
      localField: "inbox.participant",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "participants",
      pipeline: [{$project: {first_name: 1, last_name: 1, _id: 1}}]
  }},
  {$set: {
      participants: {$map: {
          input: "$participants",
          in: {$mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {added_at: {$arrayElemAt: [
                    "$inbox.added_at",
                    {$indexOfArray: ["$inbox.participant", "$$this._id"]}
              ]}}
          ]}
      }}
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cN-wGpvjJBN)